# node.js find date in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, timestamp

i'm trying to query my mongoDB collection but can't get results.

this is my nodeJS code:

```
db.collection('events', function (err, collection) {
    var now = new Date().toISOString();
    var query = {endTime:{$gte:{$date: now}}};
    console.log(query); // --> { endTime: { '$gte': { '$date': '2017-10-18T08:31:04.864Z' } } }

    collection.find(query).toArray(function(err, items) {
        console.log(items); // --> []
    });
});
```

but if i run this query via mongoDB Compass

```
{ endTime: { "$gte": { "$date": "2017-10-18T08:31:04.864Z" } } }
```

it works! (12 results)

any help? i think i'm missing something really basic here. thanks

Comment: `{endTime:{$gte: new Date() }}`. `$date` is not a real thing, but a BSON serialization from [MongoDB extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/). Which is not supported in the driver.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks! I didn't know about that $date thing